# wpf listbox and datatemplate with grid inside

Tags: wpf, listbox, grid, datatemplate

I have a following question. I want to have `ListBox` with `DataTemplate` as `Grid`. This grid has 2 two columns. I want to set first column width to `3*` and another to `*`. How to do this? I will copy my code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="commandListbox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="icon" />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
</ListBox>
```

Comment: The thread isn't very helpful.  It isn't clear what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 7):

Better to store the template in resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="GridItem" Width="200">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <TextBlock x:Name="Parameter" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,1,0,0" />
       <TextBlock x:Name="Value" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Age}" Margin="85,1,0,0" />

       <Line x:Name="Separator" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="20" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
   </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

ListBox define:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
```

In code C#:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

 public int Age
 {
   get;
   set;
 }
}
```

Define ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> MyListBoxData = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

And add items on collection:

```
MyListBoxData.Add(new Person()
{
  Name = "Nick",
  Age = 21,
});

MyListBoxData.Add(new Person()
{
  Name = "Adam",
  Age = 11,
});

MyListBox.ItemsSource = MyListBoxData;
```

**EDITED:**

Then set Width="3*", Width="*" and Margin="-WidthGrid" of the first TextBlock:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridItem" Width="300">
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <TextBlock x:Name="Parameter" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="-220,0,0,0" />
 <TextBlock x:Name="Value" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Age}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: i don't want to set constant values or auto. That's not answer for my question. I want to have 2 columns which one contains 3/4 of screen and another 1/4.

Answer (score 6):

Use IsSharedSizeScope to share column sizing across the generated grids, for Auto widths (can't be done for * sizing):

via http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
     Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value }" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

[See MSDN remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Columns and rows participating in size sharing do not respect Star sizing. In this scenario, Star sizing is treated as Auto.
>   Grid size sharing does not work if IsSharedSizeScope is set to true within a resource template, and a SharedSizeGroup is defined outside of that template.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListBox x:Name="commandListbox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="icon" />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
</ListBox>
```

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for 3/4th space for 1st column and 1/4th space for 2nd column. Setting the width in the above format must be solving the problem.

Hope it solves.