# Carousel type scrolling

Tags: c#

Using c#, what would be the best way to achieve a 2D carousel.

What would be better WPF or Windows Form. And how would be the best way to animate it? Just gradually move the pixels using a timer style ticks?

like (psuedo code):

```
//draw carousel here
using Timer every tick move the images left slightly
```

Thanks

MORE INFO:

I want it to be going quite fast as there will be 30 images and i want it to scroll through and loop once or twice before selecting a random one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF all the way! The easiest way is to create a UserControl with a ListBox and bind your collection of items to it. The trick is how you contain those items.

Here's a sample I coded a while back:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The same can also be done using a StackPanel with `Orientation="Horizontal"` and `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`.

Any questions, let a brother know.

Sorry, missed this part:

> And how would be the best way to animate it? Just gradually move the pixels using a timer style ticks?

The best way would be to use WPF's Storyboard and Animation classes. The general idea is to:

1. Have forward/backward arrows.
2. Depending on arrow clicked, either remove first item and add new item to end of list, or remove last item and insert item at beginning of list.
3. Use animations to simulating adding/removing, i.e., fade out an item (or slide to left/right, whatever), then when the animation has completed, remove the actual item from the bound collection.

Also, make sure the bound collection has variable number of items (10 in my sample) and use another collection to keep track of the next item to be removed and added.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however i dont want buttons i am going to make it use an event that get triggered i want it to roll automatically.

Comment: You don't even need buttons. Whatever is causing the carousel to move left or right (i.e., adding/removing items) can just as easily initiate an item add/removal. You'll need a routed event and, of course, know what object is to cause the event so you can attach it. If you need a timer, you can use the one in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace and perform the initiating each time it ticks. The timer would essentially be your forward/backward arrows. You can also create a flag to indicate what direction the carousel is to go in and set this flag when it is to be one or the other.

Comment: Am i able to use this with images? I.e. each box/content is a image that is linked in?

Comment: You'll need a DataTemplate for that. The original question on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211595/wpf-listbox-and-datatemplate-with-grid-inside, shows how you can do that.